# Dynamic Programming Fibonacci Number

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I am trying to implement an approach using memoization for calculating the nth Fibonacci number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int fib(int n, vector<int> v) {
    int result = 0;
    if (v[n] != 0) {
        return v[n];
    }

    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        result = 1;
    }
    else {
        result = fib(n - 1, v) + fib(n - 2, v);
    }

    v[n] = result;
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 12;
    vector<int> v(n + 1, 0);

    cout << fib(n, v);
}
```

However, I get this error.

> runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000110 overflowed to 0x60200000010c (stl_vector.h)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34

How do I change the solution to resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should compare n to the size of the vector, instead.

Comment: You also want to pass the vector by reference so that your memos are actually preserved instead of acting on a copy of the memo vector `v`.

Comment: And maybe switch to double instead of ints since you’re also having an integer overflow

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @MarouaneFazouane, int32 can fit first 46 numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are copying the vector for each call, so you don't fill initial the vector by numbers.
2. You have to use `unsigned long long` to calculate more numbers (actually 93 of them). `int` can fit only 46 (1836311903).
3. I would check the vector size inside of the function instead of creating it outside.

Use

```
unsigned long long fib(int n, vector <unsigned long long> &v) {
```

Full code: https://ideone.com/3Ipjgo

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

unsigned long long fib(int n, vector <unsigned long long> &v)
{
  if (v.size() <= n)
    v.resize(n + 1);

  if (v[n])
    return v[n];

  return v[n] = n <= 2 ? 1 : fib(n - 1, v) + fib(n - 2, v);
}

int main()
{
  vector <unsigned long long> v;

  cout << fib(12, v) << endl;

  for (int q=1; q<=94; ++q)
    cout << q << ' ' << fib(q, v) << endl;
    
  return 0;
}
```